# Playa Reverse Relationship - not working

Tags: templates, playa, relationships

I've looked at [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/getting-reverse-related-entries-via-playa) which confirms that as far as I can tell that I am doing things correctly.

I have two channels: Divisions and Zoo Visitor (members). In the zoo visitor channel I have a field "division" where the member selects the division or divisions that they belong to. Then in the divisions template I want to list the members in that division. The code I am using is below.

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="divisions" limit="1" disable="categories|pagination"}
    <h3>{title}</h3>

    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x240&text=[img 600*240]" />

    {divisions-content}


<hr />
    {exp:playa:parents channel="zoo_visitor"}
    playa field
      {title}    
    {/exp:playa:parents}
<hr />

  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

However this code is not outputting anything, not even playa field inside the playa tag pair. I've also tried adding this parameter to the playa field pair: `disable="categories|category_fields|pagination"` but nothing changes. I've triple checked that I'm on a page where the reverse relationship should be working.

Please advise.

Comment: Sean, when you say the tag is not outputting anything - are you getting your first title out of the channel entries tag (ie: if you remove the Playa tag, do you get your divisions entries?)

Comment: Lisa - yes the first channel entries tag is working fine - I get the title and the divisions-content fields output.

Comment: Probably not a playa issue as I cannot get zoo_visitor channel to display on a blank template. Have created a new support request with the Zoo Visitor developers here: http://bit.ly/XLmVyV

Comment: Thanks for the update, Sean! Please let us know what you find out. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sean, you may need to add a status parameter to your playa tag like so: {exp:playa:parents channel="zoo_visitor" status="not closed"}.

Zoo Visitor uses a custom status per member group and the playa tag will only pull in those with an Open status by default.

Comment: In my experience, this is exactly the problem. It pops up 9/10 for me.

Comment: Thanks - added status="not closed" and everything is good.